# MongoDB ruby driver is on top of the javascript driver?

Tags: mongodb

I wonder if the ruby driver for MongoDB is using the native javascript driver, or is it using c++ directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MongoDB language center](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center), the Ruby driver is hosted [here](http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver).

All of the code in the /lib/ folder appears to be Ruby code. This kind of makes sense, as you probably want the driver to work on the various Ruby interpreters and therefore want it all in pure Ruby.

If you want specific details, I would talk to [Kyle Banker](http://github.com/banker) directly. He's the maintainer of the Ruby drivers and likely knows the specific details. If you don't use github, the other way to contact him is via the [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user), where he answers questions regularly.